# TF30063: You are not authorized to access

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have VS2010 in my win2003 box. Most of the time, i am getting the Error "TF30063: You are not authorized to access xxxxx", when try to connect to TFS. i have read many blogs, everyone is telling this is because of Nuget. But i have not installed any Nuget in my system. Still i am getting the same. I have uninstalled VS2010 and reinstalled it. still problem is coming. please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

I have NuGet so this may not help you, but the solution that worked for me was to add my TFS server (e.g. https://vstf-london-01.partners.thingnet.blah.com) to the list of trusted sites in IE9 as suggested [by sirkirby in NuGet Work Item 725](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/725)

Answer (score 1):

I and some other at work have had this problem too. It was after they installed VS 2010 SP1. The solution was to go into the internet settings (i do it through IE > Internet Options) and adding the path to your TFS server to the trusted sites list in the Security tab.

Hope it helps

Comment: I found this response to be most accurate.  Thanks, Gargamel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your TFS security? Check your security and/or group memberships. You can use TFS Management Console to check all these. TFS Management Console should be in the server where your TFS service is installed. If you can't find what you're looking for, download and install TFS Power Tools (it's free) and run Best Practices Analyzer and you'll find if there are errors on your TFS configuration. If there isn't, then it's definitely how you're setting your security.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd273718.aspx
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f

Answer (score 0):

Go to Team -> Connect TFS, enter your TFS credentials, select your projects, click Connect and you should be all set

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in a 2 domain structure, where the TFS domain didn't trust the client domain. Therefor I used TFS domain credentials to connect to TFS, but got this error. I solved this issues by adding my users credentials into the Credential Manager (Server 2008 R2), as Windows credentials (`TFSServer`) and as Generic Credentials (`http://TFSServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Windows Authentication hasn't been disabled for the Website / Application within IIS that is running TFS (probably called Team Foundation Server).

I'm not sure HOW this happened, but I did uninstall Hyper-V today to be able to install VMWare Player and then re-install Hyper-V. It got disabled somewhere along the line.

Reenabling this allowed everything to work again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I has similar exception when I was configuring TFS 2013 build service.My Team foundation Server is inside the firewall, but the build server is outside the firewall. in the event viewer the error says:
[image: TF30063: You are not authorized to access]

My problem turned out to be domain trust difference as indicated here [Specify the account used to connect to your Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx)
,browse to the bottom of the page for this topic and refer to image similar to below:[image]